# How can I stop execution of User's code after x milliseconds in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to stop execution of code accepted from user after 500 or so milliseconds? I am accepting a few functions from the user and obviously do not want him to have no limits. I want to halt the execution of the function statements as soon as it crosses 500 milliseconds mark.

Right now, I will be directly embedding the code taken from user directly into mine. I know that is not the safest way but i am working on a very short timeframe and that is a problem I can tackle within a few days of putting out the first version.

Comment: JS is nearly always single-threaded. In the browser, it's nearly always the same thread that is running the HTML/CSS/browser UI; if you are running code the end-user is giving you, then not only might you not be able to stop it, you might not be able to close the tab or hit the back button, or use buttons/links on the page.

Comment: I can take the whole execution server side if there is a way to execute it in the safer environment. None of the code accesses the DOM.

Comment: It's not really a safer environment (you're giving the user access to your filesystem/database/etc). Also, what type of server are you running? Node? It's still single-threaded; a single user's code is going to hold up all other users from accessing your server...  ...if their code takes 3 minutes, that's 3 minutes that nobody else can even connect to your server (including the guy who uploaded the code).

Comment: I am sorry, I should have provided more details. This code need not be executed on a user's request. I can queue it on a separate machine from where the result will be fetched at  a later time. Immediacy is not a concern.
Which is why the looming question for me is how to prevent the user from taking over my server's time. I am not averse to writing some server side code or installing a program solely for this purpose.
After that has been figured out, I can work on safely embedding user's code with mine.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Web Workers API (specifically terminate() method) is the way to go:

https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

If it's node.js, e.g.: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads